# How to automatically find the right PDF height, according to the HTML content, in order to NOT generate useless blank space or miss content in page?

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, puppeteer, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

```
(async () => {
    const baseUrl = 'example.com';
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true});
    const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();

    function delay(time) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(resolve, time)
        });
    }

    await page.goto(baseUrl);
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1200,
        height: 800
      });

    await page.waitForSelector('[name="loginfmt"]');
    await page.type('[name="loginfmt"]', 'abc@amazon.com');
    await page.click('[type="submit"]');
    delay(1000);
    await page.authenticate({ username: `abc@amazon.com`, password: `abc@123` });

    await delay(2000);
     async function autoScroll(page){
         await page.evaluate(async () => {
           await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              var totalHeight = 0;
              var distance = 10000;
               var timer = setInterval(() => {
                     var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                     window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                    totalHeight += distance;
    
                    if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
                         clearInterval(timer);
                        resolve();
                    }
                 }, 100);
            });
         })
     }
    await autoScroll(page);

    await delay(2000);
    await page.pdf(
        {
            path: "1.pdf",
            printBackground: true,
           
        }
    )

    browser.close();
})()
```

This was an approach which I got from `GitHub` and `Stack Overflow` regarding auto scrolling of the page. But I was not able to get the entire page in my pdf after generated. I would like to get a solution for both horizontal and vertical scrolling so that none of the content gets missed in my generated pdf.

Currently have been using the below code to get full pdf. This is not the dynamic approach to get the full page of the PDF as I have given height `15000px` manually.
For the present page it will work fine but for the other pages with the height less than `15000px` it would result in an empty space at the end which is not the desired way.

```
await page.pdf(
        {
            path: "1.pdf",
            printBackground: true,
            height: "15000px"
           
        }
    )
```

Looking if we can dynamically render the `height` and `width` of the entire page so that I can pass them in the `page.pdf` by storing them in the variables before the `page.pdf function` which would give the correct dimensions of the individual page correctly.

I have been trying to fix this since a long time. It would be really helpful if I get a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

**The height of the page depends on the Page CSS.**

When we try to give "ctrl+P" ,we can see whether the page CSS supports auto scroll feature by default or not.

If Yes, then we can get it by default.

If No, will have to change page CSS in order to support Autoscrolling.